# Docker-compose re-run existing contain

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Yesterday I created a docker container with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

(and docker-compose.yaml file). It created a wordpress site, a database, phpmyadmin, etc.)

I made some changes to the wordpress installation, content, etc. I then shut it down with:

```
docker-compose down -volumes
```

This morning I wanted to run this container again and run the docker-compose up -d command again and when I visited the url it showed a wordpress configuration wizard instead of the existing installation from yesterday. In hindsight, it makes sense. Not sure why I expected not to create a new container. I then deleted the install* file from wp-admin but it didn't help.

1. Are the changes from my yesterday's wp installation lost? Have I overwritten everything?
2. Generally, how can I re-start an existing container with docker/docker-compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using `docker-compose down --volumes` you deleting :

> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

you may use `docker-compsoe start/stop` instead to stop or start your running containers

Notice: Newer docker versions use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 2):

The command

> docker-compose down

will stop all your containers, **delete** all your containers and remove any networks defined in your docker compose file.

It does not remove your volumes, by the way (unless you additonally pass the *-v* flag to the command).

So your command

> docker-compose down --volumes

will also remove any volumes.

If you want to persist your wordpress installation for development purpose but want to be able to remove and create containers during development you can mount volumes on your host machine. E.g. for your database data or also for your wordpress source code (if needed).

See also here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Take a look at the docker compose file provided there and specifically take a look at the ***volume*** directives.

In the example the database files are mounted on your host machine so that they don't vanish if you remove the database container.

If you are already using volumes in your docker compose file than you can simply *remove the **--volumes** flag* from the *docker-compose down* command

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate a service inside compose file with following command.
for example you have wordpress,mysql,nginx services inside compose file.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -f --build wordpress
```

this command recreate your container